# MariaDB 10.2.4, JSON_REMOVE error

Tags: json, mariadb

in my MariaDB 10.2.4 i have record:

```
id: 3
name: Jumper
category_id: 3
attributes: {"sensor_type": "CMOS", "processor": "Digic DV I", "scanning_system": "progressive", "mount_type": "PL", "monitor_type": "LCD"}
```

i get error:

```
Error in query (4038): Syntax error in JSON text in argument 1 to function 'json_remove' at position 86
```

when trying to:

```
UPDATE `products`
SET `attributes` = JSON_REMOVE(attributes , '$.mount_type')
WHERE`category_id` = 3;
```

JSON_EXTRACT, JSON_INSERT (and others) work ok with "attributes" as first argument.
Can anyone help?
Y

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was a bug fixed by [this commit](https://github.com/MariaDB/server/commit/76f6c1e1ed2c48594832e20035cd15fec9c35d94) in scope of [MDEV-12262](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-12262). The fix is already available on github, and will be included in MariaDB **10.2.5**-rc which is expected to be released in the next few days.

Comment: thanx for the info!